# jQuery - getting attribute from HTML Text - IE not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using and $.ajax method to get an html text. 
I would like to parse this html, getting the "src" from an "img" tag. 
I've done this way:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "image1.html", 
    success: function(msg){                  
        var htmlCode = $(msg).html(); 
        var title = $("#immagine", htmlCode).attr("src"); 
        alert( title);
    }
});
```

I can get the right result from Firefox and Chrome. They alert the correct "src" value (ex: 'pics/image.jpg'). But IE return an "undefined" alert.
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the HTML markup that's being returned?  Also, why don't you just do `$('#immagine', msg)` instead of parsing the HTML, getting it again and then parsing it again?

Comment: I've done it, but nothing change.

Comment: This is the content of "image1.html": <img id="immagine" src="pics/image3.jpg">
And the result of the alert is: pics/image3.jpg with chrome, and firefox (with my solution and the other two here posted), but always the alert with the word 'undefined' in IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know why that works in any browser, the context should be an element, a document or a jQuery object, not a string.

Use the jQuery object as context instead of getting the html code from it:

```
var code = $(msg); 
var title = $("#immagine", code).attr("src"); 
alert( title);
```

Comment: same problem! I always got this "undefined" alert

Comment: @Mauro: Is the HTML code valid? What does it look like? I tried with the value `var msg = '<div><img id="immagine" src="asdf" /></div>';` and it works in IE.

Comment: There was an error in the HTML code! I've closed a <b> tag with </> This mistaque was invalidating HTML! Thanks a lot dude.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
var htmlCode = $(msg).html(); 
var title = $("#immagine", htmlCode).attr("src");
```

The first line wraps the response in a jQuery object, but then uses `html()` to return the same HTML that the message was in the first place. Then, you wrap the source again.

You should use:

```
$(msg).find("#immagine").attr("src");
```

... to get the `src`

Comment: still undefined alert! and still working on chrome and firefox